# How to position antd notification - i want it to be centered

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

Im using this

```
export function notificationWithIcon(type, title, description, placement) {
  notification[type]({
    message: title,
    description: description,
    placement
  });
}
```

However, the only options are `topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft or topLeft`

I would like it to appear in the center of my screen. Is there any way to achieve that

EDIT: I used Majid's idea and this is how it looks like now. It's still positioned a bit to the right

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to show notification in the `[top|bottom]-center`  or 'center-center'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [documentations](https://ant.design/components/notification/):

> A notification box can appear from the topRight, bottomRight,
> bottomLeft or topLeft of the viewport.

But you can customize it yourself with `css classes`:

```
.ant-notification-center {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50% !important;
  margin-right: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and use the `notification` same as following sample:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Button, notification, Space } from "antd";
import { RadiusUpleftOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const openNotification = (placement) => {
  notification.info({
    message: `Notification ${placement}`,
    duration: 10000,
    description:
      "This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification.",
    placement
  });
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Space>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => openNotification("center")}>
        <RadiusUpleftOutlined />
        center
      </Button>
    </Space>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

[image: Edit Placement - antd@4.18.6 (forked)]

Comment: Thank you Majid! I tried this but the notification is not really centered now. I will post a picture in the edit

Answer (score 2):

You can set your notification as

```
const [api, contextHolder] = notification.useNotification();
```

and then call it as shown below:

```
api.info({
      message: `Notification`,
      description: 'bla bla bla',
      placement: 'top',
});
```

by default it should be centered if you didn't override antd css style.

try it in my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-notification-placement-9mfu5z?file=/demo.tsx:549-781)

P.S. You also might be interested in [antd message](https://ant.design/components/message)